# open specific page of pdf through xml

Tags: pdf

I am trying to open a pdf through xml. It working fine. Here is the xml tag for that :

```
<indexdata><key name="analyst">
    <topic name="analyst" url="folderName/pdfDocs/analyst.pdf"/>
</key></indexdata>
```

Its working well. But now I want to open the specific page (say, page no. 6) of this "analist.pdf" using the xml.

Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#page=4 should work.

<indexdata><key name="analyst">
        <topic name="analyst" url="folderName/pdfDocs/analyst.pdf#page=4"/>
</key></indexdata>
```

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Comment: <indexdata><key name="analyst">
        <topic name="analyst" url="folderName/pdfDocs/analyst.pdf#page=4"/>
</key></indexdata>
not working. It only works for href like "http://www.testpdf.com/analyst.pdf#page=4" but if you are open a already downloaded pdf from your local system #page=4 not works.